# Spring Security - password hashing

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, hash

I use Spring Security to handle authorization in my application. In my config I have the following:

```
<security:authentication-manager>  
    <security:authentication-provider>  
        <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>  
        <security:jdbc-user-service id="userService"
                    data-source-ref="dataSource"
                    users-by-username-query="select phone, password, true from users where phone=?"
                    authorities-by-username-query="select phone,'ROLE_USER' from users where phone=?" />
    </security:authentication-provider>  
</security:authentication-manager>
```

When I remove `<security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>` line and store in DB raw password, authorization works fine. But when I'm trying to store in DB hashed passwords, and use this line, authorization fails. Am I doing something wrong?

P.S. Password hash in DB is 100% correct. `202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70` for `123` password.

Comment: Do you hash the entered password when the DB passwords are hashed?

Comment: No, I thought that's why I need to use <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>  , it ain't right?

Comment: How do you compare the entered password with the one in the database? Please update your question with your code.

Comment: I don't compare it. Spring Security must do it

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest to you create Test class and there create hash.

```
  import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;

    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Md5PasswordEncoder encoderMD5 = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
            String securePass = encoderMD5.encodePassword("admin", null);
            System.out.println(encoderMD5.isPasswordValid(securePass,"admin", null));
        }
    }
```

In xml use

```
<bean name="md5" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"/>

<security:password-encoder ref="md5"/>
```

And of course check your hash password value at database

From me recommend to use **bcrypt**

In xml

```
<bean name="bcryptEncode" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="12"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<security:password-encoder ref="bcryptEncode"/>
```

Encoded password you can get this way:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

public class PrintBCryptString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
        System.out.println(encoder.matches("type here some string", encoder.encode("type here some string")));
        System.out.println(encoder.encode("type here some string"));
    }
}
```

Maybe will be useful small [explanation of bcrypt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6cmuiTBZVs)

Comment: I don't user salt in my application, so I tried to use "" and null as salt in this test. Both cases was successful, so I think problem is not with wrong hashing.
Yes, I know that bcrypt is much better then md5, but I need to use only md5 for some reasons.

Comment: @gth99 share please your db table users